# Is there a way to return all records where the next record on a specific column has a value from previous record + 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala

I have table with 2 columns: Year And Month.

Example:

```
Year    |     Month
1. 2020            9
2. 2020            8
3. 2020            7
4. 2020            5
5. 2020            4
```

I don,t have record for 06.2020, so as a result i want to get only all the results before the break: 1,2,3

```
Example 2:
1. 2020 12
2. 2020 11
3. 2020 10
4. 2020 09
5. 2020 08
6. 2020 07
7. 2020 05
8. 2020 04
9. 2020 02
```

I want to get as result: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: This is "gaps and islands" task - and you need "first" island only.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when next_yyyymm <> year * 12 + month + 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by year desc, month desc) as num_misses
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(year * 12 + month) over (order by year, month) as next_yyyymm
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
where num_misses = 0;
```

This adds up the number of misses up to a given year/month combination.  It returns the rows with no missing month.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a09a9fdc1c98060c17c60e36e3ee5534) is a db<>fiddle showing both examples.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

For table t with 8 records:

2020 12
2020 11
2020 10
2020 9
2020 8
2020 6
2020 5
2020 4

returns an empty result

If I change the condition from where num_misses = 0 to where num_misses = 1, it returns 1 record: 2020 4

Comment: @Fur1at . . . It didn't work.  It does now.  I was just confused on increasing versus decreasing dates.